# RSpec testing relationship logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm testing the following:

Account

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :brands, :through => :ownerships
end
```

Ownership join model

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Test

```
it "should be able to apply for brand ownership" do
  account = Account.create(valid_account_attributes)
  account.ownerships.create(:brand => Brand.create(:name => 'Superuser'))
  account.ownerships.first.state == 'pending'
end
```

And I keep getting this error

```
You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

I really don't get it - what parent? Shouldn't all the models be created and saved when using 'create'-method? I've tried putting 'account.save' everywhere.

Comment: i think there is a validation error somewhere. So #save or #create returned false. Am facing this issue myself. In my case i was mocking the return type by using build ie. not saving the object

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `account` is actually saved? Did you try using `create!` to see if any exceptions are raised?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I thought I had deleted all rows of my tables but still had one with a user, the same user I was trying to insert with the command. I solved the problem by erasing the line.